# Is it possible to include block elements in un-ordered list elements horizontally laid out

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items that I want to be laid out horizontally.  It's basically a row of pictures with captions.  Something like

```
picture1 picture2 picture3  
caption1 caption2 caption3
```

So I figured that was a unordered list with List elements styled with "display: inline".  But the captions have to be block elements otherwise they are printed in line like this:

```
picture1 caption1 picture2 caption2 ...
```

But when they're block elements the list stays vertical:

```
picture1  
caption1  
picture2  
caption2  
picture3  
caption3
```

Do I need to use floated divs instead of a list in this case?  What's the best way to make this work?

Below is a complete example using divs instead of images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head>
<title>Blah</title>
<style type="text/css">

.myclass li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
.item{
  display: inline;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="myclass">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="item"><a href="http://google.com">one</a><p>uno</p></div></li>
    <li><div class="item"><a href="http://google.com">two</a><p>dos</p></div></li>
    <li><div class="item"><a href="http://google.com">three</a><p>tres</p></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a block-level element, all the layout shifts down, even if it's container is displayed inline.

Floating your LIs is the way to go; that way you can have any content inside them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `div`s.  Just set `.myclass li` to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work in firefox, but not IE7.  Good info though.  I wasn't aware of that option.

Comment: Then I would guess that either your page is putting IE7 into quirks mode or I've forgotten something significant. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The divs in the li elements are redundent. Here is the simplest way to do it:

The HTML:

```
<ul id="captions">
   <li><a href="#"><img /></a><p>Caption here</p></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img /></a><p>Caption here</p></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img /></a><p>Caption here</p></li>
   <li><a href="#"><img /></a><p>Caption here</p></li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
#captions {
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
#captions li {
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:200px;
   height:220px;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
```